# Using a variable across the pages in PHP

Tags: php, html, netbeans

I have a login page where you enter user name and password, if correct the submit button sends you to the valid user page

in the valid user page, you enter some data then submit to go to paying page

how to get the username in the pay page?? note that the $usertext=$_POST["username"];  stopped at the valid user page

LOGIN PAGE:

```
<?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","2421993");
    if (!$con)
     {die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }

     mysql_select_db("trial", $con);


$usertext=$_POST["username"];
$passwordtext=$_POST["password"];
// if exists in database
header("Location: http://localhost/lab6/valid.php");
?>
```

VALID PAGE

```
<html>



    <head></head>

    <body  style="background-color:lightgrey">


    <h1  align="middle"> Welcome to Smart Garage Services </h1> 

       <form name="input" action="pay.php" method="post">

          Choose the area:
          <select name="place">
            <option value="6october">6 October</option>
            <option value="Zayed">Zayed</option>
          </select>

          <input type="submit" value="Go to Paying" />
    </form>
    </body>

   </html>
```

PAY PAGE:

```
 <?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","2421993");
    if (!$con)
     {die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }

     mysql_select_db("trial", $con);



    $placetext=$_POST["place"]; 

    mysql_query("UPDATE clients SET place='$placetext' WHERE Username= '$usertext' "); 
// PROBLEM IS HERE: USERTEXT variable doesn't have the user as valid page
?>
```

Comment: @Sourbah here is the question

Comment: $_SESSION variable usage would suit you. Look into sessions.

Comment: @CodeX, i cannot answer this question below because i am restricted as this question is marked duplicate. But will try to explain what to do. If you intend to use a variable across various php pages and you cannot GET/POST the values then you have the option of using session variables in PHP. In every page to use session variable at the start of code use this function `<?php session_start();` . After that assign value to that variable in format like `$_SESSION['userttext'] = "yourvalue";`. You can use that value accross multiple pages where you have the session started.  I hope this helps you.

Comment: @Sourabh Thanks alot!! to the point..